Prove that the limit of ratio of consecutive fibonacci numbers exists
I'm going to prove that the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}}$ exists.
Proof:
We will prove that the sequence is a cauchy sequence.
We have that:
$$
\left|\frac{f_{n+1}}{f_n}-\frac{f_n}{f_{n-1}}\right|=
\left|\frac{f_{n+1}f_{n-1}-(f_n)^2}{f_n f_{n-1}}\right|=
\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{f_n f_{n-1}}\right|\leq \frac{1}{f_n f_{n-1}}.
$$
We have that $\frac{1}{f_n f_{n-1}}$ is a  subsequence of $\frac{1}{n}$ and converges to 0. Therefore our sequence is a cauchy sequence and we are done.
My question is if my argument that this is a subsequence of $\frac{1}{n}$ works and proves that the fibonacci ratio sequence is a cauchy sequence.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
